# How can I boot Windows 95 on a VM directly from the hardware?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-95

I have an Asus Eee PC X101ch with an Intel Atom N2600. I need to run Windows 95 on it, but it doesn't work natively. Only through a VM.

Is it somehow posible to boot to a virutal machine? Like:

> BIOS → VM software → VM → OS → program

It should be like VirtualBox in fullscreen, but bootable and as fast as possible.

Comment: Possibly you could boot from a USB stick or a bootable CD or an external HD and then salvage your data from the hard disk.

Comment: I think you dont get it... The os i want to run IN THE VM is not compatible with my physical computer (but is compatible with vm). I want to make it so i have the fastest vm i could ever get (possibly without os).

Comment: I have an old but reliable laser printer, and I use it with W98, as I have never found later drivers that are compatible. The main reason I cannot boot into W98 directly is that there is too much memory, over the 2GB addressing limit, so I use a VM to restrict this. If you can install less memory, or tell your BIOS to use only part of what's installed, then you may be able to use native W95.

Comment: The bios is brutally restricted, no way. Belive me, there is no way other than vm/emulator.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Next time please just rewrite the question starting with the important things, no "EDIT" markers. That makes it much easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: There are products that will do this, but they're expensive and designed for servers.  Look at http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a small linux distro to boot and have that run the VM software at startup.  You could do this by changing the default runlevel to single user mode and having init run startx with the appropriate commands in your .xinitrc to run your VM software in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Good idea, try the Xen hypervisor, not sure if it'll boot Windows 95 though.

Comment: Yeah, what distro would you recommend?

Comment: @Jan4V - If you are new to Linux I would start with something like Debian or Ubuntu - Unless HDD space is a constraint - because of the ease of installing packages such as VirtualBox.  Once you get it up and running you can customize the boot up to meet your needs.  Another thread suggests Slitaz http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/small-linux-host-for-virtual-box, which I haven't used before but does look promising in its simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I follow your example, but with Windows 7 and newer you can [boot from a VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825691.aspx).  The VHD is the virtual hard disk of a virtual machine.  VHD boot allows you to boot the OS on the VHD.  However, at that point its not a VM anymore, its a live machine.  Changes to the OS/disk will be saved to the VHD.  This means if you boot to your "normal" OS, and then boot the VM associated with the VHD, those changes would be reflected there.

Comment: Nope, vhd booting supports only windows 7+ guests i think. But good idea.